# how to maxima of a function in Matlab script file?

Tags: matlab, function, optimization

I have a function to be optimized to find its maxima (using Matlab). The function part of the simulation model and hence it is stored in a Matlab script file.

Note that in normal case of function usage, I can do the maximization using ***fminbnd*** command and then taking the negative of the function. Such that

> g(x) = –f(x)

e.g.

```
[x fval] = fminbnd(@(x)-tan(cos(x)),3,8)
```

But I am looking for a way to do find maxima using the (or -ve of function to find maxima) for a script function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are looking for, you have a set of commands that take some input variable(s), and produce a result, but these commands are located within a script file rather than a MATLAB function. You want to run ***fminbnd*** on the script, rather than rewriting the commands into a function?

The obvious question is why don't you want to take the easy option and put the code into a function. Assuming you can't, for some reason, how about constructing a 'container' function that runs your script and returns the result? Something like:

```
function result = containerFunction(myScriptName, inputData)

% Input Arguments:
% myScriptName : string, filename (not extension), e.g. 'myScript'
% inputData : any data compatible with the script defined in myScriptName

% Output Arguments:
% result : must be created by the script defined in myScriptName

eval(myScriptName);
```

You can then call ***containerFunction*** from ***fminbnd*** instead.